# Chili pepper identification

Tags: identification, peppers, chili

I've recently picked pepper from plant that suffered from early frost. Plant was in a pot, about 1 meter high, with many branches and a loot of fruit like one from the pictures below. Fruit was hanging downwards. (Unfortunately I didn't take picture of whole plant).

[image]

What variety is this pepper and is it possible to harvest seeds for next season? Also, if it is spicey how many Scoville units it may have?

Comment: I can't answer authoritatively on the type but from someone that does not do "spicy" it looks to me like a ghost pepper which is extremely hot (this is a comment because I could be very off though ) or similar.  If it is a Ghost pepper you should be able to grow it from seed (you should be able to grow most peppers from seeds - but it may not be true to form if its an F1 Hybrid).

Comment: It seems to have the wrong form for a ghost pepper, which in my garden are very wrinkled; the form could be regional, though. In my relatively short-season area, they also only grow 18 inches tall or less.